# Identity Server 4 is not redirecting to Angular app after login

Tags: angular, authentication, identityserver4, asp.net-identity-2, oidc-client-js

I am using `oidc-client` in angular. following this [Tutorial](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Angular/SPA-Authentiction-using-OpenID-Connect-Angular-CLI-and-oidc-client)

```
import { UserManager, UserManagerSettings, User } from 'oidc-client';
```

**My Client:**

```
export function getClientSettings(): UserManagerSettings {
return {
authority: 'https://localhost:44305/',
client_id: 'angular_spa',
redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback',
post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/',
response_type: 'id_token token',
scope: 'openid profile api1',
filterProtocolClaims: true,
loadUserInfo: true,
automaticSilentRenew: false
};
```

In Identity Server I'm using `Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI, Version=2.1.3.0`

I'm adding default identity like this:

```
[assembly: 
HostingStartup(typeof(WebApp.Areas.Identity.IdentityHostingStartup))]
namespace WebApp.Areas.Identity 
{
   public class IdentityHostingStartup: IHostingStartup {
     public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder) {
       builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
         services.AddDbContext < WebAppContext > (options =>
             options.UseSqlite(context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WebAppContextConnection")));

         services.AddDefaultIdentity < WebAppUser > ()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores < WebAppContext > ();
     });
    }
  }
}
```

`WebAppUser` is derived from `IdentityUser`

**Startup.cs:**

```
public class Startup
{

    private ILogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService> _logger;
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public Startup(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService>();
        _env = env;
    }
    private static void SetupIdentityServer(IdentityServerOptions identityServerOptions)
    {
        identityServerOptions.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = new PathString("/Identity/Account/Login");
        //  identityServerOptions.Cors.CorsPolicyName = "CorsPolicy";
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder
             .WithOrigins("https://localhost:44305")
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        }));

        //  services.AddMvc();
        var cors = new DefaultCorsPolicyService(_logger)
        {
            AllowAll = true
        };

        var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "mycert.pfx"), "xxxxx");
        services.AddIdentityServer(SetupIdentityServer)//SetupIdentityServer
                 .AddSigningCredential(cert)
                 .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                 .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                 // .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)
                 .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources());
                 services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>(cors);

    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        //loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.Map("/api", api =>
        {
            api.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin());
            api.UseAuthentication();

            api.Run(async context =>
            {
                var result = await context.AuthenticateAsync("api");
                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    return;
                }

                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("API Response!"));
            });
        });

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        //Run these PMC commands after this.
        //Add - Migration CreateIdentitySchema
        //Update - Database

    }
}
```

In identity server 4 i have enabled `https`. So the problem is that from my Angular app if i try to use a protected `URL` I'm navigated to identity serves login page. Looks like it is authenticating properly against the user that is in database. but then it just refreshes the login page and does not redirects to the callback `URL`.

here are some logs that might help

> 2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 30.553 - 06: 00[INF] Starting IdentityServer4 version 2.3 .2 .0
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 30.632 - 06: 00[INF] You are using the in -memory version of the persisted grant store.This will store consent decisions, authorization codes, refresh and reference tokens in memory only.If you are using any of those features in production, you want to
>   switch to a different store implementation.
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 30.643 - 06: 00[INF] Using the
>   default authentication scheme idsrv
>   for IdentityServer
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 30.644 - 06: 00[DBG] Using idsrv as
>   default ASP.NET Core scheme
>   for authentication
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 30.644 - 06: 00[DBG] Using Identity.External as
>   default ASP.NET Core scheme
>   for sign - in
>    2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 30.645 - 06: 00[DBG] Using Identity.External as
>   default ASP.NET Core scheme
>   for sign - out
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 30.645 - 06: 00[DBG] Using idsrv as
>   default ASP.NET Core scheme
>   for challenge
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 30.645 - 06: 00[DBG] Using idsrv as
>   default ASP.NET Core scheme
>   for forbid
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.463 - 06: 00[DBG] CORS request made
>   for path: /.well-known/openid - configuration from origin: http: //localhost:4200
>    2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.468 - 06: 00[DBG] AllowAll true, so origin: http: //localhost:4200 is allowed
>    2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.468 - 06: 00[DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: http: //localhost:4200
>    2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.482 - 06: 00[DBG] Login Url: /Identity/Account / Login
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.482 - 06: 00[DBG] Login Return Url Parameter: ReturnUrl
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.482 - 06: 00[DBG] Logout Url: /Account/Logout
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.482 - 06: 00[DBG] ConsentUrl Url: /consent
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.482 - 06: 00[DBG] Consent Return Url Parameter: returnUrl
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.482 - 06: 00[DBG] Error Url: /home/error
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.482 - 06: 00[DBG] Error Id Parameter: errorId
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.497 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.550 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.553 - 06: 00[DBG] Request path / .well - known / openid - configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.569 - 06: 00[DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.569 - 06: 00[INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
>   for / .well - known / openid - configuration
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.576 - 06: 00[DBG] Start discovery request
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.885 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.885 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.885 - 06: 00[DBG] Request path / connect / authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.893 - 06: 00[DBG] Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.893 - 06: 00[INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
>   for / connect / authorize
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.904 - 06: 00[DBG] Start authorize request
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.919 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.935 - 06: 00[DBG] **No user present in authorize request**
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.945 - 06: 00[DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 31.983 - 06: 00[DBG] client configuration validation
>   for client angular_spa succeeded.
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 32.069 - 06: 00[DBG] Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 32.099 - 06: 00[INF] ValidatedAuthorizeRequest {
>    "ClientId": "angular_spa",
>    "ClientName": "Angular 4 Client",
>    "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:4200/auth-callback",
>    "AllowedRedirectUris": ["http://localhost:4200/auth-callback", "http://localhost:4200/silent-refresh.html"],
>    "SubjectId": "anonymous",
>    "ResponseType": "id_token token",
>    "ResponseMode": "fragment",
>    "GrantType": "implicit",
>    "RequestedScopes": "openid profile api1",
>    "State": "cd6df66e397546d3aab62533de28a2d2",
>    "UiLocales": null,
>    "Nonce": "8b3af6331d784e9a9cad076555f16174",
>    "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null,
>    "DisplayMode": null,
>    "PromptMode": null,
>    "MaxAge": null,
>    "LoginHint": null,
>    "SessionId": null,
>    "Raw": {
>     "client_id": "angular_spa",
>     "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:4200/auth-callback",
>     "response_type": "id_token token",
>     "scope": "openid profile api1",
>     "state": "cd6df66e397546d3aab62533de28a2d2",
>     "nonce": "8b3af6331d784e9a9cad076555f16174"
>    },
>    "$type": "AuthorizeRequestValidationLog"
>   }
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 32.126 - 06: 00[INF] Showing login: User is not authenticated
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 32.154 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 32.155 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 32.628 - 06: 00[INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed out.
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 40.844 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 40.844 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.517 - 06: 00[INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application signed in .
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.518 - 06: 00[INF] User logged in .
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.528 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.528 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.528 - 06: 00[DBG] Request path / connect / authorize / callback matched to endpoint type Authorize
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.529 - 06: 00[DBG] Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.529 - 06: 00[INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint
>   for / connect / authorize / callback
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.535 - 06: 00[DBG] Start authorize callback request
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.536 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.541 - 06: 00[DBG] No user present in authorize request
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.541 - 06: 00[DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.541 - 06: 00[DBG] client configuration validation
>   for client angular_spa succeeded.
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.541 - 06: 00[DBG] Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.541 - 06: 00[INF] ValidatedAuthorizeRequest {
>    "ClientId": "angular_spa",
>    "ClientName": "Angular 4 Client",
>    "RedirectUri": "http://localhost:4200/auth-callback",
>    "AllowedRedirectUris": ["http://localhost:4200/auth-callback", "http://localhost:4200/silent-refresh.html"],
>    "SubjectId": "anonymous",
>    "ResponseType": "id_token token",
>    "ResponseMode": "fragment",
>    "GrantType": "implicit",
>    "RequestedScopes": "openid profile api1",
>    "State": "cd6df66e397546d3aab62533de28a2d2",
>    "UiLocales": null,
>    "Nonce": "8b3af6331d784e9a9cad076555f16174",
>    "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null,
>    "DisplayMode": null,
>    "PromptMode": null,
>    "MaxAge": null,
>    "LoginHint": null,
>    "SessionId": null,
>    "Raw": {
>     "client_id": "angular_spa",
>     "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:4200/auth-callback",
>     "response_type": "id_token token",
>     "scope": "openid profile api1",
>     "state": "cd6df66e397546d3aab62533de28a2d2",
>     "nonce": "8b3af6331d784e9a9cad076555f16174"
>    },
>    "$type": "AuthorizeRequestValidationLog"
>   }
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.541 - 06: 00[INF] Showing login: User is not authenticated
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.552 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.553 - 06: 00[INF] idsrv was not authenticated.Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed
>   2019 - 03 - 07 01: 19: 41.553 - 06: 00[INF] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.External signed out.

**sorry i tried to format the logs properly but didn't worked.**

**UPDATE**

my server side config looks like this

```
 public class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
{
    new ApiResource("api1", "My API")
};
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
{
    new Client
    {

        ClientSecrets =
        {
            new Secret("superSecretPassword".Sha256())
        },


            ClientId = "angular_spa",
            ClientName = "Angular 4 Client",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ImplicitAndClientCredentials ,  //implicit
            AllowedScopes = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "userInfo", "api1" },

            //AllowedScopes = new List<string> { StandardScopes.OpenId, StandardScopes.Profile, StandardScopes.Email },
     RedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:4200/auth-callback", "http://localhost:4200/silent-refresh.html"},
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> { "http://localhost:4200/" },
            AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> { "http://localhost:4200" },
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            Enabled = true,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true
    }
};
    }
    public static List<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
{
    new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
    new IdentityResources.Profile() // <-- usefull
};
    }
}
```

my project structure looks like this

[image]

it doesn't have any controllers. Should it have ?

**UPDATE 2**
looks like i figured out whats wrong.

The `returnUrl` is not resolving properly on the `POST` method. it is coming as the complete `URL`. if i force it to a proper return `URL` it works

[image]

```
           var redirect_uri =  HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(returnUrl).Get("redirect_uri");
```

I did as above and used variable 'redirect_uri' in Redirect function. it works but it looks like a hack. Should it automatically get the right thing ?

with this i get 'No state in response' error on Angular side and `oidc-client` have no user after redirect.

**UPDATE**

Looks like I'm using some different `nuget` package.
`HttpContext.SignInAsync` has following constructors.

My `HttpContext` seems to be defined in

*Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages*

looks like i have wrong Nugets or something. i am trying to supply a proper ClaimsPrincipal as well but not working.

[image]

Comment: hav you tried this 'http://localhost:4200/auth-callback#' as redirect url

Comment: Could you try seting `AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ImplicitAndClientCredentials` to just `AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit`?

Comment: # at the end of url gives page not found error.

Comment: i also tried 
GrantTypes.Implicit not change

Comment: @penleychan and Fateh
check the second update. it might help you to figureout whats wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see there's a bit of confusion concerning the difference between the returnUrl and the redirect_uri. Although the end goal is a redirect to the client's redirect_uri, after authentication the client must actually redirect to the authorize endpoint for further processing (hence the reason why the url is different). You shouldn't need to change the returnUrl at all and can leave it the way it was.

The problem you're facing now is you're not calling [`HttpContext.SignInAsync`](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signin.html?highlight=signinasync) after a successful authentication. The `SignInAsync` method is used to administer a cookie with the user's information that tells the endpoint at the returnUrl that the user was successfully authenticated, and it's okay to return a token to the redirect_uri. There are a lot of [overloads for the `SignInAsync`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/63a50d7838af25896fbf836ea4e4f37b5e179cd8/src/Extensions/HttpContextAuthenticationExtensions.cs), but the one I find easiest to use is `HttpContext.SignInAsync(string subject, params Claim[] claims)`. After doing this you should be able to finish the authentication.

Comment: Not at my machine right not but so eager to test this. This totally makes sense. Ill let you know in a but

Comment: please check the update. any idea how to supply a proper claims principal? also note that claims are coming out to be 0 because while registering it looks like i am not adding claims to users.

Comment: You should be able to use the ```SignInAsync``` extension method with the IdentityServer4 package installed (and the implementation for IdentityServer4 does a little more than the regular extension method). If you'd like to call ```SignInAsync``` with the regular ASP.NET Core extension method for testing you can call ```new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims))``` where ```claims``` is your list of claims. As for the reason of why there's no claims belonging to the signed in user is all dependent on the claims that go into the ```SignInAsync``` method

Comment: @Randy You saved my life !! I had a similar problem like this. My client was native xamarin client and after login the user shows not authenticated (on event viewer). I was using a custom signing manager and not authenticating the HTTP context. the user was valid and the token endpoint was not returned. By this answer you save my time dear..  I appreciate lot. Keep helping people. Thanks one again.

Answer (score -1):

*Identity server configuration*

Set RedirectUris to your angular application hosted url.

*Angular application*

openIDImplicitFlowConfiguration.redirect_url = this.oidcConfigService.clientConfiguration.redirect_url;